# compare and remove sublist in list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list example

```
list1=[[2,4],[5,10],[6,7],[8,9],[11,14],[13,16]]
```

I want to remove complete sublists based on condition. 2nd element inside sublist is greater than next sublist. so i have pop the sublist until the condition is satisfied.

The output of list should be

```
final_list1=[[2,4],[5,10],[11,14],[13,16]]
```

Comment: wheres the code that should do this and what does not work with it?

Comment: This should be pretty simple. Just think a little bit about it.

Comment: @Hozikimaru: Can you tell me logic please. so that i can write the code.

Comment: @jnstudent no. SO is not for individuals to complete your homework for you. You should read about what type of questions should actually be posted to SO.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about the conditions under which a sublist will be removed?  It sounds like if the current pair is `(x, y)`, you keep discarding pairs until you see `(y+1, z)`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: No, if 2nd element in sublist should be lesser than next sublist both element, if not the sublist should be removed until the condition satisfies.

Comment: Why is `[8,9]` removed ?

Comment: @scharette: Because 2nd element in 2nd sublist: 10 is greater than that sublist(8,9)

Comment: `[5,10],[6,7],[8,9]`  10 is bigger then 7 and 9 so both are removed

Comment: Try starting with a for loop and and empty list :) Append to the empty list only if next indexes' elem[-1] is less than current

Comment: Logic: create an empty list. Iterate through your list, add the 1st element, for the next element check if its 2nd value is bigger then your new lists last elements 2nd value, if so add, else dont add. Do until finished. Done.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Yes, In [5,10],[6,7],[8,9] 10 is bigger than both element in sublist [6,7],[8,9]

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Not clear with the logic. but i will try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Appending to a list in a loop is the way to go here but if you wanted an inefficient, overly complicated one-liner: `[x for i, x in enumerate(list1) if i <= dict((tuple(v), k) for k, v in enumerate(sorted(list1, key=lambda y: y[1])))[tuple(x)]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to do this

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda lst,e: (lst+[e] if lst[-1][1]<=e[0] or lst[-1][1]<=e[1] else lst), [[list1[0]]] + list1[1:])

[[2, 4], [5, 10], [11, 14], [13, 16]]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It worked

Comment: This is a bad place to use `functools.reduce()`. It's really inefficient because you are creating a new list by adding in each iteration.

Comment: @pault I just chose `reduce` as the list size was small and I wanted to do one-liner. For bigger lists you can do something like `lst=[list1[0]];  _ = [lst.append(e) for e in list1[1:] if lst[-1][1]<=e[0] or lst[-1][1]<=e[1]]; print(lst)`